# Word count down unable to work in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have found out a scripting language for word count in some reference on the net. And the scripting is like this

```
<script language = "Javascript">
function tbLimit() {
    var tbObj = event.srcElement;
    if (tbObj.value.length == tbObj.maxLength * 1) return false;
}
function tbCount(visCnt) {
    var tbObj = event.srcElement;
    if (tbObj.value.length > tbObj.maxLength * 1) tbObj.value = tbObj.value.substring(0, tbObj.maxLength * 1);
    if (visCnt) visCnt.innerText = tbObj.maxLength - tbObj.value.length;
}
</script>
```

I have inserted this into my aspx pages just after my content place holder. And in order to link and call this script in my page i type this code into my page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["LoginAs"] != "PoliceStaff")
        {
            Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                LoadGrid();

                tbOR.Attributes.Add("onkeypress", "return tbLimit();");
                tbOR.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "return tbCount(" + lblCounts.ClientID + ");");
                tbOR.Attributes.Add("maxLength", "500");

            }

        }

    }
```

I have also added a label which will run the word count like this

```
You have <asp:Label ID="lblCounts" runat="server" Text="500"></asp:Label> &nbsp;characters left.
```

Can anyone see what is going wrong which is preventing this from running?

Comment: Remember to follow the standard, use `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Answer (score 1):

Very close, you need to tell Javascript the ClientID is a string by adding quotes inside the parameter to `tbCount`:

```
tbOR.Attributes.Add("onkeyup", "return tbCount('" + lblCounts.ClientID + "');");
```

Then in your Javascript, look for it using `document.GetElementById`:

```
function tbCount(visCnt) {
    visCntInput = document.getElementById(visCnt);
    var tbObj = event.srcElement;
    if (tbObj.value.length > tbObj.maxLength * 1) tbObj.value = tbObj.value.substring(0, tbObj.maxLength * 1);
    if (visCntInput) visCntInput.innerText = tbObj.maxLength - tbObj.value.length;
}
```

At the moment, you are assuming `ClientID` returns a reference to a DOM object where in reality it returns you a client-side `ID` so that you can locate the object.

Comment: Try logging the `visCntInput` variable and see if it's populated. Are you using IE? Because `event.srcElement` is IE-only.